# Position menu bars to left of aside, without affecting other elements

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

Here is the the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nh23g40n/46/

`Why does it require we post code if we provide a fiddle...whats the point..`

Hit the animate button if you cant see the white menu bars. Basically, I want the menu bars to be slightly left of that yellow side bar, and animate with the sidebar as it opens and closes. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css `left` property with some value you wanted to `fa-bars`. like

```
.fa-bars {
    ...
    ...
    left: 10px;
}
```

I think this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: wtf?! I coulda sworn i already tried adding a negative `left` value, weird. Anyway, yup, using `position: relative;
    top:100px;
    left: -50px;` worked. Thanks.